# Sequelize putting data in wrong columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm very new to mysql, so I'm sure this is something easily fixed, but when I create a new row in my database with sequelize, two of the data points end up in the wrong columns, almost like they are being switched.

Example screenshot:
[image: switched columns]

First here is my setup code:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const sequelize = new Sequelize('example', 'root', 'password', {
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost'
});

// my model for creating a new row
const Product = sequelize.define('product', {
    id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    title: Sequelize.STRING,
    price: {
        type: Sequelize.DOUBLE,
        allowNull: false
    },
    description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    },
    imageUrl: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false
    }
})
```

Then the data is coming through a form via POST request to an express server. The request is routed to this middleware function, which uses the data to create a row in the database. This is where I think the problem is:

```
exports.postAddProduct = (req, res, next) =>{
    
    const title = req.body.title;
    const imageUrl = req.body.imageUrl;
    const price = req.body.price;
    const description = req.body.description;

    Product.create({
        title: title,
        price: price,
        description: description,
        imageUrl: imageUrl
    }).then( result => {
        console.log(result);
    }).catch(err => {console.log(err)});
};
```

When the 'result' is logged to the console the data  appears as it should. Below is what I see in the console. (Note the description and URL in the correct place):

```
dataValues: {
    id: 15,
    title: 'title',
    price: '66.99',
    description: 'Description',
    imageUrl: 'URL'
}
```

But, as you can see in the screenshot linked above, what actually ends up in the database is an object that switches the values of the description and imageUrl:

```
{
    id: 15,
    title: 'title',
    price: '66.99',
    description: 'URL',
    imageUrl: 'Description'
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to remove `id=15`, and after that re-create the record? Or, in other words, if the record with id=15 does exist, what happens when you try to add it again?

Comment: I hadn't considered that because the id is set to auto increment. When I set autoincrement to false and then set the id manually to 15 I get an error "Error: Duplicate entry '15' for key 'products.PRIMARY' "